# OpenERP Java API CreateObject Error

Tags: odoo, java

I get an error for following code. Object is hr.attendance. Can some one please guide me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, XmlRpcException 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Session openERPSession;
    openERPSession = new Session("localhost", 8069, "Demo", "admin", "demo@2013");

try {
       // startSession logs into the server and keeps the userid of the logged in user
       openERPSession.startSession();
       ObjectAdapter partnerAd = openERPSession.getObjectAdapter("hr.attendance");
        ////// 
        ////// Example code snippet goes here
        //////

        Object[] ids = new Object[] {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        RowCollection partners = partnerAd.readObject(ids, new String[]{"action","action_desc", "day", "employee_id", "sheet_id"});

        for (Row row : partners){
             System.out.println("Row ID: " + row.getID()+"Action:" + row.get("action")+" day" + row.get("day")+" EmpName" + ((Object[])row.get("employee_id"))[1].toString()+" EmpId" + ((Object[])row.get("employee_id"))[0].toString()+"/ "+row.get("employee_id"));

        }

        Row newPartner = partnerAd.getNewRow(new String[]{"action", "day", "employee_id"});
        newPartner.put("action", "sign_out");
        newPartner.put("day", "2013-07-03");
        newPartner.put("employee_id", new Object[] {"2","Fabien Pinckaers"});
        partnerAd.createObject(newPartner);

        System.out.println("New Row ID: " + newPartner.getID());

   } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Error while reading data from server:\n\n" + e.getMessage());
  }

}
```

Error message (When I debug, then error get thrown when at createObject line. Please help
Error while reading data from server:
For input string: "[Ljava.lang.Object;@dd462c"

I tried passing employee_id in both formats as mentioned below.
1. newPartner.put("employee_id", 2);
2. newPartner.put("employee_id", "2");
But both time I ended up with following error again
Error while reading data from server:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
The reason I was trying to passing object as in first posting was because when I read the values from iterating, I had to cast as (Please take a look at my code)

```
((Object[])row.get("employee_id"))[0].toString() &
((Object[])row.get("employee_id"))[1].toString()
```

to read employee id and employee name out of the object. Actually I was expecting only employee to be present there. Then I thought that I might need to cast it back to object to insert also. But ended up failing.

However when I tried inserting without employee_id object. It worked. When I check field type of employee_id, it was many to one at Setting=>Database Structure -> Models for "hr.attendance" How do I insert in case if field is many 2 one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, All thanks to Pieter.

https://sourceforge.net/p/openerpjavaapi/discussion/general/thread/871410e3/?limit=25#bf63